# Restricting emojis and some of the speacial characters while entering data in an edit textbox

Tags: android, android-edittext, special-characters, emoji, restriction

I am trying to restrict some of the special characters and emojis while entering data in the edit text box.

I want to set the edit text box to error as soon as a special character or an emoji is entered. I am able to do this only for special characters, but not for emojis.

I have tried to do this by custom keyboard, for which I should set the custom keyboard every time I open the app.  I have even tried by using the input filter and included the set of emojis(i.e ":-)",":-(" etc) in the filter, but this is not working.

Below is my code:

```
public class ValidateRemarks implements InputFilter {
    EditText editText;
    String spcl;
    public ValidateRemarks(EditText editText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.editText = editText;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

           boolean valid=checkcharacters(source,i);
            if (!valid) {
                editText.setError("Cannot use this character");
                return "";
            }
            editText.setError(null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    boolean checkcharacters(CharSequence s, int j){
        boolean flag=false;

    final String[] emojis = new String[] { ":-)",":-(",";-)", ":-P",
         "=-O", ":-*", ":O","B-)", ":-$",":-!", ":-[" , "O:-)",":-\\" ,
          ":'(",":-X",":-D","o_O"};
         if(emojis.toString().contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(j))))
        {

            flag=false;
        }
        else
        {
           flag=true;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

please help me solve the issue.

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: @Muhammad Babar I want to restrict emojis and if as soon as it is entered , I want to set the error to the edit textbox. I am not able to restrict the emojis.

Comment: I understand what i meant to ask is what problem occuring with above code as your code seems right.